# Passing Record Id to LWC then to APEX

Tags: apex, lightning, lightning-web-components, component, web

This is a two part question with the following code:

contactSheet.js:

```
    import { LightningElement, wire, api } from 'lwc';
import getContactList from '@salesforce/apex/ContactList.getContactList';

export default class ContactSheet extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @wire(getContactList, {accountid: '$recordId'}) contacts;
}
```

contactSheet.html:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="ContactSheet" icon-name="custom:custom63">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <template if:true={contacts.data}>
                <template for:each={contacts.data} for:item="contact">
                    <p key={contact.Id}>{contact.Name}</p>
                </template>
            </template>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Apex:

```
public with sharing class ContactList {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Contact> getContactList(string accountid) {
        String account = accountid;
        return [
            SELECT Id, Name, Title, Phone, Email
            FROM Contact
            WHERE AccountId = :account
        ];
    }
}
```

1. I am having difficulty properly passing the records Id into the LWC and then to the APEX to properly query a list of Contacts
2. I would like to have this functionality live on the Opportunity and am having difficulty making it available on the opportunity page layout.

Any assistance you can provide would be appreciated -- I am pretty new to LWCs

Thanks,

Comment: in the future, please include any documentation links you may have read. Additionally, [Trailhead's](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/) is a great place to start and learn if you are new to lwc. cheers!

Answer (score 4):

> I am having difficulty properly passing the records Id into the LWC and then to the APEX to properly query a list of Contacts

You need to use the target `lightning__RecordPage` in order to allow the component to be used on a type of record that will support `@api recordId`.

Note that you really *should* consider using the Id data type here:

```
public static List<Contact> getContactList(Id accountid) {
```

> I would like to have this functionality live on the Opportunity and am having difficulty making it available on the opportunity page layout.

You need a `targets` and `targetConfigs` section in your metadata file. You can read more about that in [Configuration File Tags](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/48.0/lwc/lwc.reference_configuration_tags) and [Component Configuration File](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/48.0/lwc/lwc.create_components_meta_file).

Note that, for an Opportunity, your targetConfig needs to include the Opportunity object:

```
<targetConfigs>
  <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
    <objects>
      <object>Opportunity</object>
    </objects>
  </targetConfig>
</targetConfigs>
```

Also, in your case, the record Id will be an Opportunity Id, so you'll need to query that first to get the AccountId, and from there, you can get the contacts.